# Call length and specific items of list inside a list

Tags: java, arrays, list

Please view image for the scenario I want to describe.

[image: Please view image for the scenario I want to describe]

I want to have a list inside a list and know what is the size of that list (inside) and how to call a particular data from that list.
--also please include how to add the `hobbyList` into `candidateList`

So let's say I want to call the size of hobbyList for the 2nd Candidate something like `<code>CandidateList(1).HobbyList.length()</code>`? or `.size()`?

What if I want to call the value of the 3rd hobby of the 2nd candidate
`CandidateList(1).HobbyList(2)`?

I don't know if I'm already clear with what I want so please don't hesitate to ask me.

Thank you! :)

Comment: If you are using Lists, use `list.get(i)` to get the `i`'th element and `list.size()` to get the size of a `List`.

Comment: I don't get your question. `CandidateList.get(1).HobbyList.size()` would give the size of the second candidate's hobby list, and `CandidateList.get(1).HobbyList.get(2)` would get the 3rd hobby in the hobby list of the 2nd candidate.

Answer (score 2):

**Hobby** Class

```
public class Hobby {
    private int id;
    private String hobby;

    public Hobby(int id, String hobby) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }
    // Getters and setters
}
```

**Candidate** Class

```
import java.util.List;
public class Candidate {
    private int id;
    private String candidateName;
    private List<Hobby> hobbies;

    public Candidate(int id, String candidateName, List<Hobby> hobbies) {
        this.id = id;
        this.candidateName = candidateName;
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
    }
    // Getters and setters
}
```

**MainClassDemo** having main method

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class MainClassDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hobby c1Hb1 = new Hobby(1, "Cricket");
        Hobby c1Hb2 = new Hobby(2, "Hockey");
        Hobby c1Hb3 = new Hobby(3, "Football");
        List<Hobby> hobbies1 = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
        hobbies1.add(c1Hb1);
        hobbies1.add(c1Hb2);
        hobbies1.add(c1Hb3);
        Candidate candidate1 = new Candidate(1, "Ankit", hobbies1);

        Hobby c2Hb1 = new Hobby(4, "FB");
        Hobby c2Hb2 = new Hobby(5, "TW");
        Hobby c2Hb3 = new Hobby(6, "INSTA");
        Hobby c2Hb4 = new Hobby(6, "Pininterest");
        Hobby c2Hb5 = new Hobby(6, "Quara");
        List<Hobby> hobbies2 = new ArrayList<Hobby>();
        hobbies2.add(c2Hb1);
        hobbies2.add(c2Hb2);
        hobbies2.add(c2Hb3);
        hobbies2.add(c2Hb4);
        hobbies2.add(c2Hb5);
        Candidate candidate2 = new Candidate(2, "Bhumi", hobbies2);

        List<Candidate> candidateList = new ArrayList<Candidate>();
        candidateList.add(candidate1);
        candidateList.add(candidate2);

        System.out.println("No of Candidates:->" + candidateList.size());
        System.out.println("Hobby list size for the 1st Candidate:->" + candidateList.get(0).getHobbies().size());
        System.out.println("Hobby list size for the 2nd Candidate:->" + candidateList.get(1).getHobbies().size());

        System.out.println("1st Hobby of 1st Candidate:->" + candidateList.get(0).getHobbies().get(0).getHobby());
        System.out.println("3rd Hobby of 2nd Candidate:->" + candidateList.get(1).getHobbies().get(2).getHobby());
    }
}
```

**Output**

No of Candidates:->**2**
Hobby list size for the 1st Candidate:->**3**
Hobby list size for the 2nd Candidate:->**5**
1st Hobby of 1st Candidate:->**Cricket**
3rd Hobby of 2nd Candidate:->**INSTA**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully.

Assuming you have a class Candidate and an class Hobby:

```
public class Candidate {
    public final List<Hobby> hobbyList = new ArrayList<>();

    ...
}

public class Hobby {
    ...
}
```

And an list of candidates:

```
List<Candidate> candidateList;
```

You would get the number of hobbies of the second candidate in the list by calling with the expression:

```
candidateList.get(1).hobbyList.size()
```

and you would get the 3rd hobby in the hobby list of the 2nd candidate with:

```
candidateList.get(1).hobbyList.get(2)
```

to add a hobby to the second candidate, you would do:

```
candidateList.get(1).hobbyList.add(hobby);
```

Now I like to encapsulate the fields of a class, at least when they can be modified, so I would make hobbyList private, and add a few methods:

```
public class Candidate {
    private final List<Hobby> hobbyList = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getHobbyCount() {
        return hobbyList.size();
    }

    public Hobby getHobby(int i) {
        return hobbyList.get(i);
    }

    public List<Hobby> getHobbies() {
        return new ArrayList<>(hobbyList);
    }

    public void addHobby(Hobby hobby) {
        hobbyList.add(hobby);
    }

    public void removeHobby(Hobby hobby) {
        hobbyList.remove(hobby);
    }

    public void removeAllHobbies() {
        hobbyList.clear();
    }
    ...
}
```

So you now can write things like:

```
candidateList.get(1).getHobbyCount();
candidateList.get(1).getHobby(2);
candidateList.get(1).add(hobby);
```

etc...